Tuple variable don't match in Rust macro?
Hello i try to implement fill array macro in Rust! And i have a problem!
My macro code:
macro_rules! fill_tensor {
    ($elem:expr; ($dim:expr, $($dims:expr),+)) => {
        vec![fill_tensor!($elem; ($($dims),+)); $dim]
    };
    ($elem:expr; $dim:expr) => {
        vec![$elem; $dim]
    };
}

When i call my macro like this
fill_tensor!(4; (3_usize, 3_usize))

All works correctly (output is 3 by 3 matrix)
But when i call this macro like this
let shape: (usize, usize) = (3_usize, 3_usize)
fill_tensor!(4; shape)

I got error
rustc: mismatched typesexpected type usize found tuple (usize, usize)
And my question is Why?
Link To Reproduce problem (Rust Playground)
I i try to see hows $dim looks in this block of code
($elem:expr; $dim:expr) => {
    vec![$elem; $dim]
};              

I make tiny change in code
macro_rules! fill_tensor {
    ($elem:expr; ($dim:expr, $($dims:expr),+)) => {
        vec![fill_tensor!($elem; ($($dims),+)); $dim]
    };
    ($elem:expr; $dim:expr) => {
        assert_eq!($shape, (3_usize, 3_usize)) 
    };
}

And i have no error assertion correct
My final question is Why this pattern  $elem:expr; ($dim:expr, $($dims:expr),+) match to (3_usize, 3_usize) but not match to this value in variable? And how to fix it?

Macros are, at their base, text- (more precisely, tokens-) based substitution. They can't see through variables, or inspect their types.
If you want to support variables, you will have to switch to a type-system-based solution. It may look like the following:
pub trait FillTensor<Elem> {
    type Output: Clone;
    fn fill_tensor(self, elem: Elem) -> Self::Output;
}

impl<Elem: Clone> FillTensor<Elem> for usize {
    type Output = Vec<Elem>;
    fn fill_tensor(self, elem: Elem) -> Self::Output {
        vec![elem; self]
    }
}

impl<Inner: FillTensor<Elem>, Elem: Clone> FillTensor<Elem> for (usize, Inner) {
    type Output = Vec<Inner::Output>;
    fn fill_tensor(self, elem: Elem) -> Self::Output {
        vec![self.1.fill_tensor(elem); self.0]
    }
}

The usage is like FillTensor::fill_tensor((3, (3, 3)), 4).
A macro can still make this a tad nicer:
macro_rules! fill_tensor {
    // A helper to translate `(dim1, dim2, dim3, ...)` to `(dim1, (dim2, (dim3, ...)))`.
    (@construct_dimension ($dim:expr $(, $dims:expr)+ $(,)?)) => {
        ($dim, fill_tensor!(@construct_dimension ($($dims),+)))
    };
    (@construct_dimension $dim:expr) => {
        $dim
    };
    
    ($elem:expr; $($dim:tt)+) => {
        FillTensor::fill_tensor(
            fill_tensor!(@construct_dimension $($dim)+),
            $elem,
        )
    };
}

The tuple flattening can also be done entirely in the type-system with a bit more complicated trait implementations (this won't allow the custom syntax, though).
